# (Python) Tesseract Installation Problem in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I've read a couple other answers on this, but I'm still stuck.  I imagine I'm doing something stupid, but this doesn't work:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

def tryTesseract(u):
    return(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(u)))


loc = 'C:\\Python\\Lineups\\558.png'

print(pytesseract)
print(tryTesseract(loc))
```

The first line prints:

> <module 'pytesseract' from 'C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\**init**.py'>

But the second prints several lines of error and culminates in:

> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.

This seems weird if the first line works.  I BELIEVE I have correctly added it to path though, and it is correctly installed, as in this screenshot:

[image: CMD screenshot]

Full error message:

[image: Python error]

Edited for exciting new error.  I followed user3250052's advice and am now getting a new error (CMD window on top of Python window here:)

[image: New error]

````
from PIL import Image

def tryTesseract(u):
    return(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(u)))


loc = os.path.join('C','Python','Lineups','558.png')
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR'

print(pytesseract)
print(tryTesseract(loc))```
````

Answer (score 1):

That is a file not fond error.
Try

```
loc = os.path.join('C','Python','Lineups','558.png')
```

you might also need

```
pytesseract.tesseract_cmdloc = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried adding that, but get the same error.  Would the line 'print(pytesseract)' work if this was the problem?

Comment: your right it wouldn't. It looks like a file not found error by the way. use os.path()

Comment: Aha, the error is now different, it just says:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C\\Python\\Lineups\\558.png'

Which is weird as I can see it in the directory.  The rest of the error is gone though...

Comment: Is it possible that the file is opened in another program?

Comment: Thanks Dunski, it was indeed open in another program - or at least, a reboot fixed the problem.  Guess I forgot the first rule of computer troubleshooting...